# Should single tag edits be approved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Title says it all.

I have seen 5+ of [these exact edits](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/576505) **by the same user**, and I'm wondering whether they should be accepted.

Comment: I reject those as a waste of my time, but other people approve them and my rejection is also wasted.

Comment: I reject in most of the cases. I accept if a tag is blatantly wrong.

Comment: If you're interested, please show some love to this feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263640/allow-us-to-filter-out-tag-only-or-minimal-edits-from-suggested-edits-review

Comment: I was getting more than 10 such edits each time I entered Q, After discussing it on chatroom ( [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30151872#30151872) , [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30152108#30152108) ) then I started to skip those.. Well now its posted on meta, i am interested what decision will be made :-)

Comment: I approve them *if* they are correct. Agreed, those add little. Every time I feel a bit robbed of my time to review them. Still, if we care about the version tags and they are correctly set, I'm okay with that. Also, I think we already had this discussion a few times.

Comment: Okay, how about I create a community wiki answer with everyone's opinions?

Comment: @AndroidDev You could but I am sure this will get a few good answers, it is a common topic of discussion here. I would give it a day or two and let people who have not answered one of these questions before post there own answers on what they think.

Comment: I approve them because I don't see a good reason not to. They're correct. Now I'd rather people avoided them, but I'm perfectly happy with approving them when it's done. Otherwise I'm wasting everyone's time.

Comment: depends on the edit, really. There is a reason the system doesn't block them.

Comment: @Seth Can we create a separate queue for tag-only edits?

Comment: @Seth And possibly lower the rep limit to review them?

Comment: Why? You used to be able to edit just the tags at 500 rep, but they removed that.

Comment: @Seth And why did they do that?

Comment: I feel Sorry that, u all are bearing that, I was doing some lazy edits and was not reviewing my suggested edits feedback for long, I will make sure not to repeat that mistake

Comment: @Hizqeel No one is trying to tell you what to edit exactly, as you can see it splits opinion here. Some of us are simply suggesting there are better, more important things that people can edit, rather than something so small.

Comment: @Hizqeel I did the same thing you did some years ago and lo-and-behold  a discussion on meta sprung up exactly like here now. I wasn't aware I kept people busy with my low-hanging-fruit-edits and changed my suggest-edits. However, the system allows minor edits for a reason. Those aren't bad *per se*. The question here is more about if the system can be better optimized in one sense or another.

Comment: @AndroidDev https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Should [sip] edits be approved?

You should just ["evaluate each edit in isolation. Approve if the edit is good, improve if it can be improved, reject if it's detrimental to the post and reject and edit if you feel that the post needs another kind of work."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314573/792066)

If you find that the editor didn't really fixed all issues with a post, then take the actions so it's known to them.

Comment: Can you please explain the last sentence *then take the actions so it's known to them*? Do you suggest to accept and improve the edit?

Comment: I suggest to act as if it was any other edit @A.L. Approve if it's good, reject if it's bad. The results will be known to the editor anyways.