# A user doesn't ask or answer, but only adds tags

Tags: discussion

I have noticed one particular user's activity is only adding tags to questions, nothing else. I see them almost daily in review queue.

The user adds mostly irrelevant tags. I reject the edits. Others accept some and reject others.

My opinion is that tag-only edits by low rep users shouldn't be accepted, because it make only noise and isn't really helpful.

Also this kind of activity as the only one is really weird.

Comment: I've thought about this myself - and also finds it rather odd. Some of the tags are sometimes relevant, but others are not.. I think I'm around 50/50 in approving and rejecting the suggested tags.

Comment: It was discussed years ago that tags-only edits is recommended to reject. Otherwise new users keep doing it. There is no much value in this activity.

Comment: That's fine for me if this is the guideline. 

Comment: Well, it was years ago. Maybe someone won't agree ;-)

Comment: How would you evaluate this post history? https://askubuntu.com/posts/1447264/timeline The user in question added tags, got approved, then 15 minutes later someone else removed them.

Comment: See also [What to do with tag-only edits?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17338/what-to-do-with-tag-only-edits) and [When is an edit too minor?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8474/when-is-an-edit-too-minor) and [Should single tag edits be approved?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15546/should-single-tag-edits-be-approved). In this specific case, I'd custom flag a post and let a mod know. In general, I think that edits should fix all issues with a post, and so updating tags on an otherwise bad post would be a fair reason to reject. I'm happy to do whatever consensus is though

Comment: I'm not sure if it's appropriate to talk about specific users in meta. Perhaps, this could have been discussed in chat with mods.

Comment: @RandomPerson why not? It's not like user activity is a secret? Also this just raises questions about a users activities. If said user wanted to reply and give an explanation, they could very well do so. In the spirit of openness, I don't see any problems with this, as long as it's done in a civilized manner.

Comment: @ArturMeinild The user is new to the network I suppose and might not know about meta.

Comment: If editing tags only is approved in Ask Ubuntu guidelines then it is approved. If it is not approved in Ask Ubuntu guidelines then either approve it or change the guidelines. We have enough rules here without making up new ones.

Comment: It is approved to reject useless edits, isn't it? So if it is approved to reject them then either reject or change the guidelines ;-)

Comment: @RandomPerson You have a reasonable point about targeting a specific user on Meta; I have edited out the user details from the question itself. The question works well enough as a *general* question of editing and usage rather than an investigation of a specific user I think.

Comment: @andrew.46 The link to a user was am example. There is another one too. I didn't want to be offensive.

Comment: @Pilot6 I see no offense and you have a legitimate question...

Answer (score 5):

My own view of an Ask Ubuntu user whose participation is mostly in making minor changes (in this case tag edits) is that *we already have mechanisms in place to deal with such occurrences*.

I borrow heavily from MSO and [Braiam's excellent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314573/7358809) to say that there are two paths to follow:

1. Look at each one of the edits in isolation and decide whether to approve the edit, improve the edit or reject the edit. This is basic to editing work across SE and needs no modification in this case
2. If there is an emerging pattern of poor edits from a particular user the system may very well catch this; if not flag for Elected Mod attention: we have tools to deal with this.

As a third point I would encourage some patience with users who are perhaps still working out *where they can best contribute to Ask Ubuntu*.

Some will end up becoming great editors, some will ask great questions, some will create incredible answers, <s>some will become great tag editors,</s> and a very small number will become great all rounders.

But in the beginning there may be some flailing around that ordinarily should respond to *gentle* guidance.